# Linux curl post request and Error 417 but sudo success?

Tags: linux, curl, docker, nginx

My service is deployed in docker,the exposed nginx port is 18082;service port is 38087,and I tried both.

while I use command

> curl -i -X POST  -H 'content-type: text/json'   -d @post.json \
>   http://127.0.0.1:18082/youtu/openliveapi/livedetectfour

return 417

```
HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation failed
Server: squid/2.7.STABLE9
Date: Tue, 15 Aug 2017 11:57:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1436
X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_REQ 0
X-Cache: MISS from SK-SQUIDDEV-118
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from SK-SQUIDDEV-118:8080
Connection: close
```

But when I add sudo in the front,it return success.
     HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
     HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: openresty/1.9.15.1

I really do search and knew while curl post over 1024 bytes,it will first send

expect 100-continue.if server don't  support that request, it will return 417 error.

then how can sudo succsess,maybe It is related to nginx mechanism,I'm not familiar with that.thanks.

Comment: Add a `-v` and see if you find anything interesting in verbose output

Comment: @TarunLalwani thank you very much...I tried -v and found I have been using company http_proxy that doesn't support expect 100..and sudo success by using no proxy,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using proxy in your corporate setup and the proxy might be insert in your user's bash profile. You can do 3 things

**Update ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc**

Remove the proxy from your profile and you won't need the proxy

**Unset the variables**

You can unset the variables before the call

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
curl -i -X POST -H 'content-type: text/json' -d @post.json \ http://127.0.0.1:18082/youtu/openliveapi/livedetectfour
```

**Blank the variables for the call**

You can set the variables just for that one curl call

```
http_proxy= https_proxy= curl -i -X POST -H 'content-type: text/json' -d @post.json \ http://127.0.0.1:18082/youtu/openliveapi/livedetectfour
```